# Error in %conda list biopython in jupyter notebook (macOS)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, importerror, biopython

I use jupyter notebook, I have anaconda installed on the system. I get this error when I import Bio

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-de5ff3e63c39> in <module>
----> 1 from Bio import Phylo
      2 import wget
      3 import re
      4 from Bio import SeqIO
      5 from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
```

and when I look at the packages in this path `/Users/morteza/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`, bio and biopython are there

Can somebody help me with this? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `%conda list biopython`?

Comment: you mean the title?

Comment: How did you install biopython? Did you create a new environment?

Comment: No I didn't create new environment, I used ```conda install biopython```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution so I share here maybe will be useful for someone. I changed the name `bio` to `Bio` in the path `/Users/morteza/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` using `mv bio Bio` command then the import worked properly.

Comment: What is your operating system? How did you install biopython exactly with conda?

Comment: masOS Catalina, I did with  ```conda install biopython``` (in terminal)

Comment: Thanks, what does `conda list | grep -i bio` show? I'm trying to understand what went wrong

Comment: Thanks, sorry of course it does! Can you just show the line with `biopython` on and any other `bio` modules?